# What do the classes ChainstateManager, CChainState, CChain and BlockManager do in Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, validation, c++

What do the classes `ChainstateManager`, `CChainState`, `CChain` and `BlockManager` do in Bitcoin Core?

Why do `CChainState` and `CChain` have a leading 'C', but `ChainstateManager` and `BlockManager` don't?

These questions were asked during the May 12th 2021 [Bitcoin Core PR review club](https://bitcoincore.reviews/21767) hosted by John Newbery on a Carl Dong PR to de-globalize ChainstateManager.

Comment: Thanks for documenting the questions from the review club here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do the classes `ChainstateManager`, `CChainState`, `CChain` and `BlockManager` do?

A graphic from [Doxygen](https://doxygen.bitcoincore.org/class_chainstate_manager.html) showing how the classes interact:

[image: Doxygen graphic]

`ChainstateManager`: Provides an interface for creating and interacting with one or two chainstates

`CChainState`: Stores and provides an API to update our local knowledge of the current best chain.

`CChain`: An in-memory indexed chain of blocks. It was introduced in [PR 3077](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/3077).

`BlockManager`: Maintains a tree of blocks (stored in `m_block_index`) which is consulted to determine where the most-work tip is.

> Why do `CChainState` and `CChain` have a leading 'C', but `ChainstateManager` and `BlockManager` don't?

C stands for class using Hungarian style naming.

The current style in Bitcoin Core is not to use Hungarian notation. Bitcoin Core uses `m_` to represent member variables, `g_` to represent globals, and no prefix to represent local variables/parameters. `CChainState` and `CChain` were named prior to these style guidelines being implemented in Bitcoin Core.

These were answered by John Newbery and other participants of the May 12th 2021 [Bitcoin Core PR review club](https://bitcoincore.reviews/21767).