# Why many classes in the Bitcoin Core prefix with a `C` while it is prohibited in the developer notes?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, c++

It's part of the developer notes in the documentation of Bitcoin Core:

> Class names, function names, and method names are UpperCamelCase
> (PascalCase). Do not prefix class names with `C`. See Internal interface
> naming style for an exception to this convention.

[Link](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/5fca70f5b16fee4a732a1d7fd3fb1c7e775decdf/doc/developer-notes.md#coding-style-c)

But I've seen many places in the codebase classes' name starting by `C`.
Such as:

- `CBlock`
- `CTransaction`
- `CTxIn`
- `CTxOut`
- `COutPoint`

And many other examples. Is there a progress currently for changing these names? Or this rule is not apply to some classes?

Note that there's no description for this inconsistency in [this part](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/5fca70f5b16fee4a732a1d7fd3fb1c7e775decdf/doc/developer-notes.md#internal-interface-guidelines) of the doc.

Comment: Related question: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/106558/what-do-the-classes-chainstatemanager-cchainstate-cchain-and-blockmanager-do-i

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These classes predate the coding style guidelines. Guidelines are a recommendation for newly added code and refactoring patches for the purpose of only changing the coding style are discouraged.

In the plain words of [the introduction of the document you link](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/5fca70f5b16fee4a732a1d7fd3fb1c7e775decdf/doc/developer-notes.md#coding-style-general):

> Various coding styles have been used during the history of the codebase, and the result is not very consistent. However, we're now trying to converge to a single style, which is specified below. When writing patches, favor the new style over attempting to mimic the surrounding style, except for move-only commits.
>
> Do not submit patches solely to modify the style of existing code.